# node spawn with sudo cannot use ipc

Tags: node.js, ipc, sudo, spawn

In my project, I need to create a child process and communicate with it via IPC, at same time, this child process must run as root. So I use `cp.spawn('sudo', ...)` with IPC channel, but I found the `process.send` method is `undefined`.

Here is the code:

**file: parent.js**

```
'use strict'

const cp = require('child_process')
const path = require('path')

const script = path.join(__dirname, 'child.js')

let child = cp.spawn('sudo', [process.execPath, script], {
  stdio: ['inherit', 'inherit', 'inherit', 'ipc']
})

child.on('message', msg => {
  console.log('message> ', msg)
})

console.log('parent> parent run!')
```

**file: child.js**

```
'use strict'

console.log('child> child run!')

process.send('hahaha')
```

**run `node parent.js`**

```
parent> parent run!
Password:
child> child run!
/Users/zoujie.wzj/workbench/child.js:5
process.send('hahaha')
        ^

TypeError: process.send is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/zoujie.wzj/workbench/child.js:5:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

*Update: After I replace `cp.spawn('sudo', ...)` with `cp.spawn(process.execPath, ...)`, the program will work:*

```
parent> parent run!
child> child run!
message>  hahaha
```

Is anyone knowns why IPC doesn't work with sudo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation:

> If the child is a Node.js process, the presence of an IPC channel will enable process.send(), process.disconnect(), process.on('disconnect'), and process.on('message') within the child.

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio

Only in the situation what you are spawning is a Node process, the `process.send()` method would be enabled.

In your situation, you are spawning a `sudo` process, and the Node running child.js is argument to `sudo` rather than spawned from parent.js. So the `process.send()` won't be enabled, **That's why child.js throwed error.**

So the `child.send()` is actually sended to the `sudo` process instead of `node child.js` as expected.

As you are asking why IPC doesn't work for sudo: **I think IPC is working**. However, as mentioned above, you are trying to IPC with `sudo` process which actually doesn't understand or won't make a response to your `child.send()` action.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing *all* the `inherit`s and IPC should work.

Be advised that your code would not print the 'hahaha' message that the child sends because you're not waiting or blocking; so when you run `parent.js`, it executes each line and silently (and cleanly) exits.

Comment: I have tried, but IPC still doesn't work. If I replace the `sudo` with `process.execPath` then IPC will work. I think the `sudo` will fork another child process, just like: `parent.js -> sudo -> child.js`.